# [react-native,WKWebview]Mistake:wk unable to acquire assertion for process 0

Tags: ios, react-native, wkwebview

*(sorry!forgive my English skill...)*
I used RCTWKWebview for a long time and run well.  But nowadays i use ten or more canvas component in my page .When I quickly slide the page it will be white screen and no response on **iPhone7Plus**(but iPhone6/7 runs well)
When i look for some in Xcode's console, I found this mistake:
**wk unable to acquire assertion for process 0.**
There seems to be a problem with memory or CPU rendering，I can't find the reason, I hope if you see can help，really thanks very much!!

Comment: The Android device and Iphone 6/6s/7 is working properly, and I feel it doesn't matter with the phone's performance and the phone's memory.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.